# Prevent Cisco from connecting to "wired connection" that's actually a virtualbox connection without admin

Tags: virtualbox, cisco-anyconnect

I'm sick and working from home, and trying to connect to my company's vpn. However, Cisco Anyconnect insists on forcing a connection with one of the virtualbox ethernet connections on the machine, preventing any kind of proper authentication, which in turn, means in our setup, I can't verify admin or connect to our vpn so our IT staff can remote-fix with their elevated permissions.

Comment: What about disabling the Virtualbox connections until the VPN is connected?

Comment: disabling requires admin

Comment: Then you need to talk with your local IT support staff, it seems.